# How to extract the DB Value and compare it with the soap response

Tags: soapui

My functionality is to test when i send the Mobile Operator, it should return the List of top up values which is related to that Operator.

1. I can able to retrieve the DB Values using JDBC request
2. I am getting success response with the list of top up values.

Here I want to test that the response actually contains the values from the DB only. How to test this? Is there any idea.. please let me know.

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groovy script:

```scala
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.sql.Sql

//those are feched from testsuite properties
def dbUrl=context.expand('${#TestSuite#Url}')
def dbUser=context.expand( '${#TestSuite#User}' )
def dbPass=context.expand( '${#TestSuite#Pass}' )
def dbDriver=context.expand( '${#TestSuite#Driver}' )

def db = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPass, dbDriver)

def dbValues = db.rows("SELECT A, B, C from TABLE ")
//is only one row?
assert dbValues.size == 1

def valueA = dbValues[0].A

//more asserts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JDBC step and then click on Add Property (+) from top of it. 
Then enter any name under "Name" column and then click in the Value field and retrieve the data from the Response using Get Data right click option.

Now connect to the DB by giving the configuration details and Driver, Connection string details and password.
Then write the DB Query in the SQL Query section as below:

```
Select * From DBName
where DB Columnname =:Name given in the property added above
```

For ex:

```
Select * From Test_DB
where sequenceid =:Sequence_Response
```